# Dict from nested dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm wondering how could I transform nested dataclasses to dict except for `None` fields. I'm aware of `asdict()` method existence, but I'm trying to write method similar to `asdict()` that will ignore empty values during `dict` creation.

For example:

```
@dataclass
class Nested:
    name: str = None
    contacts: list = field(default_factory = list)

@dataclass
class Main:
    nested: Nested = field(default_factory = Nested)
    surname: str = None
```

Expected result would be:

```
example = Main()
example_d = asdict(example)
print(example_d)

{"nested": {"contacts": []}}
```

What I have currently:

```
example = Main()
example_d = asdict(example)
print(example_d)

{"nested": {"name": None, "contacts": []}, surname: None}
```

I know that `asdict()` would ignore fields without value and given default as default, but I need `= None` during dataclass initialization.

I ended up overriding the `asdict()` and `_asdict_inner()` methods:

```
def asdict(obj, *, dict_factory=dict):
    if not _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        raise TypeError("asdict() should be called on dataclass instances")
    return _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory)


def _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory):
    if _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        result = []
        for f in fields(obj):
            value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
            result.append((f.name, value))
        return dict_factory(result)
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple) and hasattr(obj, '_fields'):
        return type(obj)(*[_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj])
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return type(obj)(_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((_asdict_inner(k, dict_factory),
                          _asdict_inner(v, dict_factory))
                         for k, v in obj.items() if v is not None) # <- Mine change to exclude None values and keys.
    else:
        return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

But it doesn't work as supposed.

Implementation of `_is_dataclass_instance` as requested. It's from the `dataclass` module.

```
def _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
    """Returns True if obj is an instance of a dataclass."""
    return not isinstance(obj, type) and hasattr(obj, _FIELDS)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could create a custom dictionary factory that drops `None` valued keys and use it with `asdict()`.

```
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(x for x in data if x[1] is not None)

example = Main()
example_d = asdict(example, dict_factory=CustomDict)
```

---

**Edit:**  Based on @user2357112-supports-monica suggestion, here's an alternative that does not use custom dictionaries.

```
def factory(data):
    return dict(x for x in data if x[1] is not None)


example = Main()
example_d = asdict(example, dict_factory=factory)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. :) Cheers mate. I was looking for examples of dictionary factory because I had no idea how it should look like. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)  BTW, you could avoid the creation of the intermediate list with `tmp1 = (x for x in data if x[1] is not None)`.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to make the dict factory a `dict` subclass. The result will be composed of instances of `CustomDict` instead of instances of `dict`, which causes a variety of weird and subtle inconsistencies with regular dicts. Why not just write a function that builds a `dict` without `None` values?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, that is an alternative.  I have updated the answer with your suggestion.  While I have heard about arguments against custom dictionaries, I am not sure they apply in simple cases such as above.